# Textfield inside nested Listview

Tags: android, ios, flutter, cross-platform

I have a Listview inside it i have a gridview which contain Textfield to add some comment ,My goal is to get the text of the textfield and store in a **List<List< Object >**, now where i am trying to read the data insize a nested listview through onChanged() but I get the the same date for every item in the parent listview.
Here is my code.

```
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 16),
                child: ListView.separated(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int parentindex) {
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('Set ${parentindex + 1}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: textColor,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                fontFamily: 'sf_pro_display',
                              )),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          GridView.builder(
                              key: UniqueKey(),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              gridDelegate:
                                  const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                                      mainAxisExtent: 40,
                                      mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                                      crossAxisSpacing: 8),
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                // print('parent $parentindex');
                                // print('item $index');
                                return textItem(parentindex, index);
                              },
                              itemCount: widget.workoutExercise
                                  .intensityPart[parentindex].length),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        const Divider(),
                    itemCount: widget.workoutExercise.intensityPart.length),
              ),
            ),
```

Textfield Widget

```
Widget textItem(int parentindex, int index) {

    return Container(
      key: ValueKey('$parentindex$index'),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: searchBoxColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
                widget.workoutExercise.intensityPart[parentindex][index]
                    ['title'],
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: darkGreyColor,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                  fontFamily: 'sf_pro_display',
                )),
            Text(" : ",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: darkGreyColor,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                  fontFamily: 'sf_pro_display',
                )),
            Expanded(
              child:TextField(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              // controller: _controllers[parentindex][index],
              maxLines: 1,
              minLines: 1,
              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
              onChanged: (text) {
                  writeData(parentindex, index, text);
              },
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: textColor),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: widget.workoutExercise.intensityPart[parentindex]
                      [index]['value'],
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: darkGreyColor),
                  border: InputBorder.none),
            )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is how i store my data

```
void writeData(int parentindex, int index, String text) {
    print('parent $parentindex');
    print('item $index');
    print('item $text');
    widget.workoutExercise.intensityPart[parentindex][index]['value'] = text;
    widget.workoutExercise.intensityPart.forEach((element) {
      element.forEach((element) {
        element.forEach((key, value) {
          print(key);
          print(value);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: i'm curious, have you solved this? thanks!

Comment: @KimLo
Yes , I had to divide my code to 2 different Screen as flutter does not allow nested list of TextField.

Comment: can i have an idea or show me how you did it? having troubles with this one also :(